# Issue display data from API in angular

Tags: angular, frontend

I am using the mailjet API for a project, and when getting template data back from the API, I would like to display a preview of the HTML. However, the html is returned as Html-part from the api and I keep getting an error when trying to display the HTML to test if the code worked.

```
// the data back from the api
Html-part: "Lorem ipsum..."

{{details.Html-part}}
```

"Cannot find name 'part'"

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Valid Characters**
*In general JavaScript, variable/function names can't contain -. They can only contain letters, $, and _ (Underscore)*

Since variables can't contain dashes, you need to use String/Bracket Notation to achieve the result:

In html you can bind to `getHtmlPart()` which should be defined in component:

```
getHtmlPart() { return this.details['Html-part']}
// this assumes details is available in component scope, replace with your  
//variable name where response is stored
```